# Perl prepared statement not using bind parameters

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

This is all being run on Windows 7 with Strawberry Perl (v 5.16.3) to a 2012 SQL Server.

I am doing something wrong here and I am at a loss on what it could be.  I can run a sql statement with the parameters included and it comes out fine.  However, if I place the SQL in the statement handle and try to bind the parameters, I get a SQL error - I suspect because the parameters did not bind.   The code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;

use DBI;
use Data::Dump qw( dump );

my $dsn = "Driver=SQL Server;Server=servername;Database=databasename;Uid=username;pwd=password";
my $dbh = DBI->connect_cached("dbi:ODBC:$dsn", undef, undef, {
        PrintError => 0,
        RaiseError => 1,
        ShowErrorStatement => 1,
        LongReadLen => 500000,
    }) or print($DBI::errstr);

my $Id = 586058;
# sql with parameter included. 
my $sql = qq~
         SELECT ps.parmId
         FROM table1 ps
            JOIN table3 pd ON pd.parmId = ps.parmId
         WHERE ps.testOccurId = $Id
            AND pd.requiredForPass = 1
         UNION
         SELECT ps.parmId
         FROM table2 ps
            JOIN table3 pd ON pd.parmId = ps.parmId
         WHERE ps.testOccurId = $Id
            AND pd.requiredForPass = 1
         ORDER BY ps.parmId
    ~;
# this works without error
my $arrayRef = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($sql);
print dump($arrayRef);  # get data

# re-write sql with parameter place holders
$sql = qq~
         SELECT ps.parmId
         FROM table1 ps
            JOIN table3 pd ON pd.parmId = ps.parmId
         WHERE ps.testOccurId = ?
            AND pd.requiredForPass = 1
         UNION
         SELECT ps.parmId
         FROM table2 ps
            JOIN table3 pd ON pd.parmId = ps.parmId
         WHERE ps.testOccurId = ?
            AND pd.requiredForPass = 1
         ORDER BY ps.parmId
    ~;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$sth->bind_param(1, $Id);
$sth->bind_param(2, $Id);
# throws SQL error because parameters are not bound to statement.
$arrayRef = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($sth);
# also does not work if we do the following:
# $arrayRef = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($sth, undef, $Id, $Id);
# we crash here and the rest does not get run.
print dump($arrayRef);

exit 0;
```

The error I receive is the following:

> DBD::ODBC::db selectall_arrayref failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver]Numeric value out of range (SQL-22003) [for Statement "
>            SELECT ps.parmId
>            FROM table1 ps
>               JOIN table3 pd ON pd.parmId = ps.parmId
>            WHERE ps.testOccurId = ?
>                   AND pd.requiredForPass = 1
>            UNION
>            SELECT ps.parmId
>            FROM table2 ps
>               JOIN table3 pd ON pd.parmId = ps.parmId
>            WHERE ps.testOccurId = ?
>                   AND pd.requiredForPass = 1
>            ORDER BY ps.parmId
>           "] at bindParametersTest.pl line 56. ]

I suspect that SQL Server says '?' is out of range of the int column we are querying against (because, technically, it is) - hence the error.  Also, because the same value works fine in the first sql where I have included it previous to running it.

I have been pouring over the documentation and I can't what I'm doing wrong.   I'm hoping another set of eyes can point out my stupid mistake.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**UPDATE:**

So I tried this code after the parameter bindings:

```
$sth->execute();
$arrayRef = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();
```

it produces this error, which shows the parameters:

> DBD::ODBC::st execute failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver]Numeric value out of range (SQL-22003) [for Statement "
>            SELECT ps.parmId
>            FROM table1 ps
>               JOIN table3 pd ON pd.parmId = ps.parmId
>            WHERE ps.testOccurId = ?
>                   AND pd.requiredForPass = 1
>            UNION
>            SELECT ps.parmId
>            FROM table1 ps
>               JOIN table3 pd ON pd.parmId = ps.parmId
>            WHERE ps.testOccurId = ?
>                   AND pd.requiredForPass = 1
>            ORDER BY ps.parmId
>           " with ParamValues: 1=586058, 2=586058] at bindParametersTest.pl line 59.

I cannot figure out why the query fails only if we bind the parameters...

Comment: Try specifying the data type when binding.

Comment: @ikegami  Well that fixed it.   It runs now.  Does the driver/DBI think that 586058 is larger than an integer, hence the problem?  We are running 32 bit perl here.

Comment: Larger than the type it defaulted to using, seems like.

Comment: `->execute($Id, $Id)` (without binding) may also have worked.

Comment: @ikegami - unfortunately, no.  the `execute($Id, $Id)` does not work.  Get the same "out of range" error.   It appears type must be specified.  Thanks for pointing that out.   It did not register with me that is should be necessary.

Comment: @ikegami If you want to put down your suggestion as an answer, I'll mark it correct.